# how to generate previous year in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

```
  private void GenerateYear()
    {
        drpYear.Items.Clear();
        int Currenyear = DateTime.Now.Year;

        for (int i = Currenyear; i >= 1990; i--)
        {
            drpYear.Items.Add(i.ToString());
        }
        drpYear.SelectedValue = Currenyear.ToString();
    }

    private void GenerateMonth(bool SetCurruntMonth, DateTime currentDate)
    {
        drpMonth.Items.Clear();
        int year = drpYear.SelectedIndex != 0 ? ((drpYear.SelectedValue != "") ? Convert.ToInt32(drpYear.SelectedValue) : currentDate.Year)
                            : currentDate.Year;

        int months = (currentDate.Year == year) ? currentDate.Month : 12;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
        {
            drpMonth.Items.Add(new ListItem(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(i), i.ToString()));
        }
        if (SetCurruntMonth == true && currentDate.Year == year)
        {
            if (currentDate.Month >= 1)
                drpMonth.Items.FindByValue(currentDate.AddMonths(-1).Month.ToString()).Selected = true;
            else
                drpMonth.Items.FindByValue("1").Selected = true;
        }
        else
        {
            drpMonth.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }
```

i done this ....i'm loading previous month in dropdown,,,but when change jan 2014,,the month dropdown is showing december but year dropdown showing 2014,,,

Note:i'm taking year,month from system date

Comment: `DateTime.Now.Year - 1`

Comment: How are the methods used ? Also, `months` seems declared but never used, is it supposed to be put in place of the hard-coded `12` in the `for` loop ?

Comment: Well, you're always selecting the current year in `GenerateYear`, why are you surprised you get the current year selected?

Comment: Please, post more info when and from where those functions (GenerateYear, GenerateMonth) are called.

Comment: My concept is i'm loading previous month name in dropdown,,,in this case i'm changing the system date jan 2014,,i m getting december month in month dropdown...but its showing 2014 year in dropdown....i want load 2013  in the dropdown,,,,guys getting it???

Answer (score 0):

I think your implemented logic is a bit off and is not exactly user friendly. You should not change values user inputs but instead provide default values only at first page load. Otherwise it is kind of funky - if I want to enter Jan 2013 I have to choose Feb 2013.

As a user I would expect that values what I select stays the same and are not automatically changed. If you need to, you can do extra calculations later after selected values are submitted.